# Can jockey wheels be used in either position in derailleur cage?

Tags: derailleur-rear

Old jockey wheels are getting toothless and I was wondering, does it make a great difference which jockey wheel goes where?

Can you use the same profile jockey wheel in either position?

Comment: I've successfully used cheap chinese jockeywheels in both positions without issue.  Both were better than what was previously there.

Comment: @Criggie I guess that would depend what was there previously, that approach would not work for anything new or higher end

Answer (score 9):

The top and bottom wheels are different. The top wheel's bearing allows some lateral movement. They come as a set and are not expensive so just replace both together.

Comment: Great answer. The only thing to add is that you should keep the same number of cogs when you buy the replacements. You can't use a different size jockey wheel especially on the top as you might have trouble shifting.

Comment: @RoboKaren Thanks. Also, larger wheels may just not fit in the cage.

Comment: The tooth shape is also different between the two wheels. One has shaped teeth and a specific turning direction. Getting that backwards will make your shifting work very poorly.

Comment: Can somebody find an explanation why jockey wheels need teeth? There was a time when they had none since their task is to guide the chain and not to transmit any power. I've had several toothless RDs from Simplex and Huret.

Comment: @Carel Interesting, you should ask that as a independent question

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are also pulley sets where the spacing is different on each, ie for a cage that's not flat.

Comment: @Carel how did they work, compared to modern derailleurs?

Comment: @ojs: They were on 2x6 speed non-indexed system and didn't work differently as any other sense and sensibility operated shifter. It was all in the wrist. A prewar bike I owned however had a 3 speed Simplex derailleur with just one jockey wheel with very long teeth, of about the normal tooth length of a cog or chainraing. Unfortunately the derailleur was changed once at a shop and vanished.